# Как определить высоту блоков?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть некоторый массив блоков, который нужно перебрать с помощью jQuery и выдать высоту каждого блока в отдельности. Но `console.log` выдает только `undefined`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var z = 0; z <= $(".d-col.d-col-9.p-b").length; z++) {
        console.log($(".d-col.d-col-9.p-b").height()[z]);
    }
});
```

В идеале скрипт должен брать высоту одного блока и присваивать другому.

Но ошибка уже на этом этапе:

```
$(function() {
    $(".d-col.d-col-9.p-b").each(function() {
        var z = $(this).height();
        $(".d-col.d-col-3.d-tac").css({
            height: z
        });
    });
});
```

Нужно присвоение высоты полученной у первого элемента его соседнему элементу.
И так для всех пар блоков.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-9 p-b"></div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-3 d-tac"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-9 p-b"></div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-3 d-tac"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-9 p-b"></div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-3 d-tac"></div>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что вы не знаете про each, поэтому вот вам пример. Пробовали так?

```
$(function(){
    $(".d-col.d-col-9.p-b").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).height());
    });
});
```

Ответ на дополнение:

Проходите each по родителям пар. Вам необходимо как-то обозвать этих родителей, я назвал .parent

Ещете через find() первый див и берете высоту в переменную. Затем, ищете второй элемент и присваиваете ее.

```
$(function(){
    $(".parent").each(function(){
        var z = $(this).find('.d-col.d-col-9.p-b').height();
        $(this).find('.d-col.d-col-3.d-tac').css({
            height: z
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Он выводит тот ответ что нужен мне.

Comment: $(function(){
    $(".d-col.d-col-9.p-b").each(function(){
      var z = $(this).height();
      $(".d-col.d-col-3.d-tac").css({
        height: z
      });
//        console.log($(this).height());
    });
  });

Comment: Но данный код не срабатывает, т.к. он присваивает блоку высоту последнего блока а не каждого из них своему.

Comment: Не совсем понятно ваше объяснение проблемы. Что вам в итоге нужно, все блоки одной высоты или что? Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Дополнил на верху

Comment: @mangoloid1 обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, все работает, но моя изначальная проблема по выравниванию блока по вертикали не работает, даже с фиксированной высотой(

Comment: @mangoloid1 что в этом ответе, что в моём ответе код (на основании представленного в вопросе) работает так, как должен. Если есть какие-то дополнительные подробности, то стоило изначально добавить их в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

покажите код `html`

может ошибка тут

> ".d-col.d-col-9.p-b" => ".d-col .d-col-9 .p-b"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var z=0; z<= $(".d-col .d-col-9 .p-b").length; z++){
      console.log($(".d-col .d-col-9 .p-b").height()[z]);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Нет, это один блок с тремя классами, а не друг в друге

Comment: @mangoloid1 покажите тогда `html`. может решение по другому можно будет сделать

Comment: Наверху .......

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev 1. Так как все три класса принадлежат одному элементу, то селектор должен быть `.d-col.d-col-9.p-b`. 2. `$("селектор").height()[z]` - так дела в jQuery не делаются.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `.each()` и `.siblings()`:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".d-col.d-col-9.p-b").each(function() {
        var height = $(this).height();
        $(this).siblings('.d-col.d-col-3.d-tac').css({ height: height });
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-9 p-b" style="height: 100px">1</div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-3 d-tac">2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-9 p-b" style="height: 200px">1</div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-3 d-tac">2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-9 p-b" style="height: 300px">1</div>
    <div class="d-col d-col-3 d-tac">2</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Верное альтернативное решение.